# BinaryExpression combination

Tags: c#

I want to combine a list of conditions in a BinaryExpression. The problem is that I want all conditions in the same level, that way:

True == True And True == False And True == True And True == True And True == True Or True == False And True == True And True == True And True == True And True == True And True == True Or True == True

But the expression is generated:

((((((((((((True == True) And (True == False)) And (True == True)) And (True == True)) And (True == True)) Or (True == False)) And (True == True)) And (True == True)) And (True == True)) And (True == True)) And (True == True)) Or (True == True))

```
var currentExpr = this.MakeExpression(list.First());
foreach (bool obj in list.Skip(1))
{
    var nextExpr = this.MakeExpression(obj);
    switch (type)
    {
        case 1: // And
            currentExpr = Expression.And(currentExpr, nextExpr);
            break;
        case 2: // Or
            currentExpr = Expression.Or(currentExpr, nextExpr);
            break;
    }
}


private BinaryExpression MakeExpression(bool value)
{
    BinaryExpression expression = Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(true),Expression.Constant(value));
    return expression;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `AndAlso` and `OrElse`? IIRC these nest them at the same level..

Comment: yes, occurs the same problem

Comment: I don't understand the question. There has to be some precedence. Either implicitly or explicitly. Just like when you write a condition statement in c#.

Comment: I too question how you expect operator precedence to be handled, For example using the [standard c# rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) here is how it ends up [being processed](http://pastebin.com/MTmUr6DK) (Disable word wrap to make it display correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with the precedence by delaying the `OR`s yourself:

```
var andExprs = new List<BinaryExpression>();
andExprs.Add(this.MakeExpression(list.First()));
foreach (bool obj in list.Skip(1))
{
    var nextExpr = this.MakeExpression(obj);
    switch (type)
    {
        case 1: // And
            andExprs[andExprs.Count-1] = Expression.And(andExprs[andExprs.Count-1], nextExpr);
            break;
        case 2: // Or
            andExprs.Add(nextExpr);
            break;
    }
}

var currentExpr = andExprs.First();
foreach (var expr in andExprs.Skip(1))
{
    currentExpr = Expression.Or(currentExpr, expr);
}
```

I can't test the code right now so there might be typos (does `andExprs.Count` need to be `andExprs.Count()`?) but that should give you the general idea.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. If all the expressions are on the same level, won't the usual C# operator precedence apply? Then the ``and``s will be performed before the ``or``s.